# The JavaScript newline cargo cult strikes again

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

There is an issue I cannot seem to get away from, even if I'd like to.

Recently I edited a bizarre question from a new JavaScript programmer with some strange ideas. He had a long line where you couldn't really see his double assignment so well. It had a horizontal scroll bar, and unnecessary scroll bars on code excerpts are a pet peeve of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26302879/revisions

Having delved (I thought) into semicolon insertion issues, I believed I'd done a legal transformation. [A comment appeared, and was upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302879/how-can-i-make-a-simple-table-row-with-numbers-using-appendchild#comment41274754_26302879):

> Did you check for syntax errors? Because while semi-colons are optional, their omission (given the linebreaks in your shown code) should generate quite a few errors.

So I was the one putting in the linebreaks, here. I asked the commenter to clarify because I didn't think that was an issue. No response was raised.

It was already a sore spot for me, because one of my few on-StackOverflow.com "in the negative total" downvoted questions *(since compensated by "meta effect", thanks but stop upvoting it)* was this one:

[Are there semicolon insertion dangers with continuing operators on next line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858171/are-there-semicolon-insertion-dangers-with-continuing-operators-on-next-line)

I bountied it for 100 points just to draw attention to it enough to get it upvoted from the negative, because I didn't feel like whining on Meta. And the bounty raised it to zero and I thought the issue was settled. Now I feel like whining, because *that question just got downvoted again*, and I *still don't have a response from the person who said the newlines were a problem* in the other (seemingly unrelated) edit.

(The code has problems, of course, but I don't believe the newlines added any new ones.)

Am I on crack and/or is this JavaScript [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) behavior? Note the "That is rubbish." answer to my claim that it's often recited. If it's rubbish, why do I see this so frequently?

Comment: `If it's rubbish, why do I see this so frequently?` Probably because of people encountering the behavior but not understanding all the cases where it can or cannot happen.

Comment: On your next edit, try to get a `goto` in the code, see how that pans out :)

Comment: You edited someone's code, you hope correctly. Someone else though it looked wrong, and left a comment (probably based on their perception the asker being a beginner, rather than as a specific critique of your edit). It wasn't asserting something definite, more a throwaway 'try this'. You started a fake question asking for people to arbitrate on what happened on the first question which you weren't happy with. Now you are starting a fake Meta question asking for people to arbitrate on what happened on the second question which you weren't happy with. Hasn't enough time been expended on this?

Comment: @jwg You commented when it was seemingly settled enough... so apparently: nope, we need more time expended.  Nothing fake about any of the questions.  It's Q&A and I'd like to know the answers.  There were no line breaks in the original question in mid-line, so I think it's legit to assume the comment was about my edit introducing them.

Comment: Obviously several downvoters of both questions thought that they were either not real questions or a waste of time in general.

Comment: Ah, the meta effect… I already wondered why I'd gotten so many upvotes on that answer lately :-)

Comment: It's not cargo-cult behavior; it's just plain old superstition. Programmers are notorious for beliefs like this; "don't use new/with/goto, a clown will eat you", "put constants before equality operators or your children will grow buckteeth", "always use braces around every statement, or you might turn into an Apple"...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va_GyIHlRfc

Comment: You shouldn't reformat someone else's code - ever.

Comment: -1: I don't see anything in the comment related to your edit - check out answer - clearly missing brace is syntax error which is what commenter said. Just because you received notification does not mean comment is to you.

Comment: @bukko There are exceptions (e.g. Python), but it's pretty widely accepted on Meta that editing code *indentation* is acceptable in order to increase readability. It's very difficult to understand a code snippet if, for example, there is a triple-nested loop all flush with the left side of the post. See [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: @Shog9 nothing's wrong with `new` (though it's not really needed), but `with` kills performance, and `goto` doesn't even work in javascript.

Comment: And black cats are unlucky if you trip over them, @Jan - it stops being superstition if you're actually avoiding specific, plausible problematic outcomes. And half the ones I listed were C superstitions, not JS.

Comment: fun fact: yoda conditionals, if used in EcmaScript 3, may actually _introduce_ some very nasty bugs if you manage to overwrite `window.undefined` with some value it shouldn't have. ES5 fixes that by making `window.undefined` unwritable - but it's still a silent error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Story seems to turn out to be that if you are trying to format JavaScript examples with line breaks, to get rid of the horizontal scroll bars, you are almost always going to be safe in doing so... *if the original line of code was syntactically valid*:

[From @apsillers new answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26345085/211160):

> The common problem people have with ASI occurs when an author has two lines which he expects will stand separately, but those two lines happen to cause no grammatical problem when understood as a single line. That case starts with two lines and they accidentally become one. Your cases is the inverse: you start with one line; it does not accidentally become two.

It's slightly more nuanced than that--but in cases one is not very likely to be able to defend as "fixing formatting", involving breaking lines at `continue`, `break`, `return`, `throw`, and postfix `++`/`--`.

The bigger problem is that you *might* make code with *illegal* syntax change behavior by adding in newlines...such that what was previously illegal becomes "legal".  Which would likely change the intended meaning of the question in the process.

Because the asker of the question I cite hadn't checked the browser's dev console (or some online validator before asking), their code had syntax errors and wasn't running.  Though theoretically throwing in newlines might have taken that broken code and "fixed it" such that it was broken in a new and different way, it didn't.  The commenter suggesting the line breaks were an issue, and the person upvoting that comment, were apparently confused.

Comment: This shows the danger of "fixing" code in questions. Far better to leave a comment asking the OP to do it for you and verify that the changed code still exhibits the same behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that the issue is cargo cult programming, I think the issue is that reformatting syntactically-invalid code is as meaningless as the original syntactically-invalid code, *unless the purpose was to highlight the error*.

You said that you believed "that it did not introduce additional errors that weren't there to begin with."

I'd argue that that statement is meaningless, or at the very least unhelpful.

If I write

```
var a = b(c= d(x)}
```

and you refactor it to

```
var a = b(
    c =  d(x)
 }
```

we've just gone from one meaningless statement to another. The reformatting is "not even wrong" because reformatting couldn't have made it right.

Now, certainly breaking up the lines *can* make a syntax error clear. I think it the original situation the reformatting did this. But it didn't appear to be the intent -- it wasn't done as an answer, it was just "fixing" the question. And I think that will cause confusion. The OP will be told they have a syntax error, and they will look at the code and say "Well, that's not the code *I* wrote. Why did someone else change my code to one with a syntax error?"

What you're asking about, though, is simply the comment that says that "[the semicolons] omission (given the linebreaks in your shown code) should generate quite a few errors." I think you should simply read this comment as saying "There is a syntax error in your code," (which there demonstrably **is**), "look at each statement, from start to semicolon, and make sure that each one is a valid statement."

Yes, the comment wasn't pinpointing the syntax error correctly, but, like a compiler, sometimes a person's best answer when looking at a syntactically-invalid statement is to say "*there's an error somewhere around here.*"

Comment: Hm, interesting. *"breaking up the lines can make a syntax error clear. I think it the original situation the refactoring did this."* => The line breaks show where the syntax errors are. --- I had not considered this interpretation of the comment at all.  But note that "reformatting" and "refactoring" are semantically different.

Comment: s/refactoring/reformatting